# Thread-safety when passing array as argument in WebAssembly? [Emscripten]

Tags: javascript, c++, browser, emscripten, webassembly

AFAIK, when passing arrays from JS to Emscripten-compiled C/C++ functions, we are essentially putting the array into a JS simulated HEAP(like `Module.HEAPU8`), which is shared by JS code and C/C++ code.

This works fine in a single-threaded environment, but how about a multi-threaded environment, like worker threads? Is there some built-in mechanism to guarantee the thread safety for this simulated HEAP?

If not, does it mean we need to call `Module._malloc()` & `Module._free()` to dynamically manage heap space for each thread? If so, this sounds like a potential performance bottleneck, given the effort for array copy and space allocation/free might compromise the benefit we gain from using worker threads.

**Reference**: [ref1](http://shockry.blogspot.com/2017/04/webassembly-sending-javascript-array-to.html) [ref2](https://becominghuman.ai/passing-and-returning-webassembly-array-parameters-a0f572c65d97)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, but it is currently impossible to share a `WebAssembly.Memory` across workers. JavaScript has [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) but WebAssembly doesn't yet support the equivalent (and compatible) [`WebAssembly.Memory` with `shared=true` attribute](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1073).

Once it is supported you'll be able to `postMessage` a `WebAssembly.Memory` and use it to instantiate multiple modules with it across workers. You'll also be able to `postMessage` the underlying `SharedArrayBuffer`, and read / write to and from it using JavaScript, concurrently with WebAssembly.

In all these cases they memory won't be copied. The WebAssembly `malloc` / `free` implementation isn't specified, but what you'll get from e.g. Emscripten will be thread safe. It won't use `grow_memory` initially (the design currently disallows growing a shared memory), but will rather pre-allocate and make sure that's thread safe for you (like any multi-threaded C implementation does).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation:)